# How to fetch values from a form in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: here is the image]

As per the image I have to fetch all the values from the required field i.e. from the TextFormField, CustomRadioButton & as well as from the `patient age` as per my requirement. On click of submit button I have to fetch those values so that I can pass them through the provider.
As I am very new to flutter, I can fetch the value from the TextFormField but couldnot able to fetch from rest of the two.

here is my UI below.

below is the code for `CustomRadioButton`

```
 Container(
                              width: 200,
                              child: CustomRadioButton(
                                customShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                elevation: 0,
                                absoluteZeroSpacing: false,
                                unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                buttonLables: [
                                  'Male',
                                  'Female',
                                ],
                                buttonValues: [
                                  "MALE",
                                  "FEMALE",
                                ],
                                buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                                radioButtonValue: (value) {
                                  print(value);
                                },
                                width: 80,
                                height: 60,
                                enableShape: true,
                                selectedBorderColor: Colors.green,
                                unSelectedBorderColor: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                                selectedColor: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
```

2. for the age picker(/*do not know I am correct or not because I had just hardcoded the text 12, but want  `+`  and  `-` should work.*/)

   ```
                    Container(
                          width: 100.0,
                          height: 55.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                              )
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                                      )
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.remove,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '12',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                                      )
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.add,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 20.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 80),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Color(0xFF888DA1),
                            child: Text('Submit',  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
                                fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white)),
                              onPressed: (){
                              submit();
                              }
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
   ```
3. This one is the function where I will fetch those values

   submit() async{
   print(nameController.text);
   }

Please help me how to do this!

Comment: It looks you are using static value `Text( '12',` for age

Comment: No, now I just hardcoded it but actually the age will be choosing by tapping on `+` or `-`. Can you please tell me how to fetch those values as well as how do I operate that `+` and `-` successfully. Please help me @Shubham Narkhede.

Comment: Yes sure just give a min will post a answer

Comment: Please check my answer and if this work for you please mark it as true and do upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here what i do first set `defaultSelected: "MALE",` and then store value in one variable and when you change the value then you
get this value from  `radioButtonValue:` this method then simply add this value to my local variable. After that for age i only added simple
`increment and decrement` logic and set this value to text

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SelectionScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}
class _selectionScreen extends State<SelectionScreen>{

  var gender = "MALE";
  int age = 12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [

            Container(
              width: 200,
              child: CustomRadioButton(
                customShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                elevation: 0,
                absoluteZeroSpacing: false,
                unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                buttonLables: [
                  'Male',
                  'Female',
                ],
                buttonValues: [
                  "MALE",
                  "FEMALE",
                ],
                buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                radioButtonValue: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    gender = value.toString();
                    print("=--->>${gender}");
                  });
                },
                width: 80,
                height: 60,
                enableShape: true,
                selectedBorderColor: Colors.green,
                unSelectedBorderColor: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                selectedColor: Colors.green,
                defaultSelected: "MALE",
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 55.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                  )
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        age--;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 25.0,
                      width: 25.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                          )
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    age.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        age++;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 25.0,
                      width: 25.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                          )
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 80),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Color(0xFF888DA1),
                      child: Text('Submit',  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
                          fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: (){
                        print("============>> Radio Button Value: $gender");
                        print("============>> Age: $age");
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ],),

          ],
        ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, everything is working fine. But on UI it is not showing the value decreasing or increasing means only it is showing 12 as it was.

Comment: and what if the age limit is up to 14?

Comment: I had checked everything it's working fine. Now you mean to say that you want to add validation for age like max age is 14 right?

Comment: yes, and on UI it is only showing 12. The thing is when we click on `+` or `-` the value should be changed. But it is showing only 12 as it was, when I hot reload it then only it is changing.

Comment: @abhipsabiswal i updated my answer you can run above example this is working fine its changing value when you click on + and - button

Comment: yes, I did it on another project. It is working perfect. But on my existing project it is not working! may be I could not find where to change , I can see the values on console, it is increasing and decreasing. Anyway many many thanks for your help! @Shubham Narkhede

Comment: @abhipsabiswal glad to help you and maybe your above tree is missing something so this is not working in your current project

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is to build a model class that will have the default values for each form element.  Then, when building the form, construct an instance of the form data class, and use the members to establish the `value:` for each item.  Wire up each of the `onChanged:` callbacks to validate the new value, and store it back into the form data instance.  On submit, send the data along its merry way.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Randal Schwartz.